# Data structure for an integer list minimizing cost of inserting, deleting and partial sums

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Let L be a list of integers, design data structure that would minimize cost of following operations:

```
Insert(i,x) - insert integer x to the list after position i
Delete(i) - remove the integer at position i from the list
Sum(i,j) - returns sum of all elements between and including positions i and j
```

I already figured out that normal linked list is much too slow for this when you work on large amounts of data.

Comment: This looks like homework, but might make an interesting interview question.

Comment: Consider a binary tree such that: (1) The list L is obtained by performing an in-order traversal of the tree; (2) at each node, the number of left child-elements either equals, or is one greater than, the number of right child-elements; (3) each node stores both the count and the sum of all child elements.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens how storing a sum of child elements would help with Sum(i,j) operation?

Comment: @DanielS: It enables the calculation of the sum of elements *1..i* in O(log N) time instead of O(N) time. Difference between *sum(I..j)* and *sum(I..i-1)* is of course *sum(i..j)*.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I just want to make sure I understand correctly.
Your suggestion is to build the tree in such a way that node with index i is a parent of all nodes with indices less then i?

Comment: @DanielS: There's something wrong with your description, because the only trees that satisfy that condition have 0, 1 or 2 nodes (if you add a 3rd node, either it needs to have both nodes 1 and 2 as parents, in which case it's not a tree, or it's missing one of them as a parent, and setting i to that node violates your rule).  Even if you replace "parent" with "ancestor" in your description, the only kind of tree you can get is essentially a linked list, since sibling nodes are forbidden.

Comment: @DanielS: No; the root of each sub-tree will be the midpoint of the sub-list it contains. This will hold for the root of the whole tree as well.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Your tree changes the order of insertion, so you can't sum the elements between 2 indexes, because you can't find those elements

Answer (score 1):

You start with any of the many methods that create a binary tree with a height that is O (log n). The elements in the tree are ordered by index. In addition to a usual tree, for each link to a subtree it also contains the number of items in that subtree and the sum of the integers in the subtree.

The number of items in the subtree makes it easy to add and remove items in the right positions. For example, if there are two subtrees with x and y items, and we want to insert an item at position i, 0 ≤ i ≤ x+y, we insert it at position i in the left subtree if i ≤ x, or at position i - x in the right subtree if i ≥ x (if i = x we can insert it in either tree), updating the number of indexes and the sum of integers for that link. If the tree needs to be balanced, the counts and sums need to be updated during the balancing as well.

It is also easy to calculate the sum in logarithmic time: To calculate the sum for i ≤ n ≤ j when the left subtree has x items and the right one has y items: If j < x calculate the sum of elements i ≤ n ≤ j in the left subtree. if i ≥ x then calculate the sum of elements i-x ≤ n ≤ j-x in the right subtree. If i < x and j ≥ x then add the sum of elements i ≤ n ≤ x-1 in the left subtree and the sum of elements 0 ≤ n ≤ j-x in the right subtree. Obviously if j - i + 1 equals the number of items in a subtree, then we take the stored sum of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

We can use AVL tree as it is balanced tree and Binary tree has worst case complexity higher than AVL.